# www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: php, xampp

When I try to open the localhost I see ( **Not Found**

**The requested URL was not found on this server.** ) and after checking the Apache(error.log) on xampp I found this message ( **[www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name** )

at first, I made sure that the Apache server was actually running, after that, I looked for some answers, and **kinsta.com** recommended adding ( **ServerName localhost: port number** ) to **httpd-ssl.conf** file, but I still get the same error, I have changed the port number many times but still, have the same issue.

this is my first time working with xampp and PHP, any ideas?

Comment: after trying the answer i got this don't error log,, [Sat Nov 12 21:42:31.642460 2022] [core:warn] [pid 8:tid 424] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Nov 12 21:42:31.673405 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8:tid 424] AH00455: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 12 21:42:31.673405 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8:tid 424] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Jun 22 2022 09:58:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after:

- launch the XAMPP Control Panel
- Click the Explorer button (This will open a file browser window in
  the XAMPP folder)
- navigate to **apache** > **conf** > **extra**
- And edited the **httpd.conf**
- I've looked for the line that reads “**Listen 80**”, and Changed
  it to “**Listen 81**”
- Also looked for the line that reads “**ServerName localhost:80**”,
  Changed it to “**ServerName localhost:81**”
- Restart Apache (stop and then start it) thru the XAMPP Control
  Panel

Thank you Ken Lee for your helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP, to fix this problem

- launch the XAMPP Control Panel
- click Explorer button (This will open a file browser window in the XAMPP folder)
- navigate to apache > conf > extra
- Edit the httpd-ssl.conf
- look for the line that reads `“ServerName www.example.com:443”`, comment it out (add a # at the front of this line)
- Add “ServerName localhost” on the line directly below it, save the file
- Restart Apache (stop and then start it) thru the XAMPP Control Panel

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, the same error(not found)